# In S3 bucket how to properly configure files in json format to be downloaded or to be read?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

My question came out when I experienced two different behaviors in **object URL** from json files stored in a s3 bucket.

Consider a json file: *mydata.json*

If I upload this file using s3 dashboard from AWS website, I am able to see data in browser: *//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/folder/mydata.json*. I am also able to read this data from a different application if I create a specific configuration in s3 bucket.

For the other hand, if I use `boto3` library for python and upload the same file in the same bucket (making file public in the process), when I click **object URL** it downloads the file, but it doesn't open data in browser.

This is the code I used:

```
# upload json file
bucket.upload_file(path, jsonkey)
object_acl = s3.ObjectAcl('bucket_name', jsonkey)
bucket_response = object_acl.put(ACL='public-read')
```

I explored file properties such as metadata. When I upload file via dashboard, the metadata assigned is `Content-Type: application/json`, and via `boto3` is `Content-Type: binary/octet-stream`. I don't really know if metadata affects the **object URL** behavior.

In this context, how can I properly configure files in json format to be downloaded or to be read? I mean, what is the main configuration that affects **object URL** behavior?

I couldn't find a significant difference between both methods (dashboard and boto3) in properties or permissions, besides `Content-Type` in metadata. However, when I tried to change `Content-Type`, behavior was the same.

Any other information I can provide to clarify this question, be free to ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for the S3 bucket resource's [upload_file()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.upload_file) method is not ideal as it simply refers you to the equivalent [S3Transfer docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html?highlight=s3transfer#boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer.upload_file) for how extra arguments can be used.

Try the following:

```
bucket.upload_file(path, jsonkey, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "application/json"})
```

Comment: Thanks. What I can't understand is why jsonfile doesn't have the option `application/json` in metadata when value is `binary/octet-stream` via boto3. And when I changed `application/json` to `binary/octet-stream` **object URL** didn't download the file, it showed data in browser again.

Comment: @jarmond For the other hand, if a csv file is the target, what is the ContentType we need to use to read data and not to download it, text/csv?

Comment: An individual browser's behavior in the absence of content-type is implementation-specific afaik. Yes, for CSV content, use text/csv.

Comment: @Ramiro Tormenta
Same for me. I think that after one time that boto3 set the ContentType to `binary/octet-stream` the file can't change to `application/json` even if you specify it with `s3_client.put_object(
Bucket=os.environ.get("BUCKET"),  
Key="data.json",
Body=json.dumps(data, indent=4),
ContentType="application/json"
 )` 
It change the meta data (I check on the s3 console) but not really.
My solution was to downloads the file. remove it from the bucket and then add it again with  `ContentType="application/json"`